# How to pass link data from one page to another page using querystring in asp net

Tags: asp.net

can you help with this please?

This link would be set up something like this:

http://.mywebsite.com/site/TR?fr_id=1131&pg=entry?utm_source=______&utm_medium=_______&utm_campaign=ABCD2015

When it is clicked, the code implemented needs to pass the source and medium info (facebook /social) into the gaps (_____) in link url.

How can i do this?

ASP is not my environment and all I know has not worked.

Can some help me please.

Comment: Do you want to pass the values in query string or trying to access the values of query string ?

Comment: Hi I think the request is to pass them, so they populate in the empty spaces please.

Comment: How you are generating your link url you can just do `"http://.mywebsite.com/site/TR?fr_id=1131&pg=entry?utm_source="+yoursourcevaluevariable.ToString()+"&utm_medium="+yourmediumvaraiblevalue.ToString()+"&utm_campaign=ABCD2015"`

Comment: It is a google analytics one that we use.

Comment: Can you show some code and explain what exactly you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: This is all I have I thought it would need some JS in the header.

Comment: If you want to integrate google analytics in you r site then take a look at http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/119/displaying-google-analytics-data-in-asp-net

Comment: Hi this wasn't clear to me, and it looks over complicated, where ever the user have come from, will be passed in the url where the user is going.

Comment: The URL was built using the GA from this page https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en-GB&ref_topic=1032998